# get the hours for every month

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have created a function which will take two parameters as startdate, enddate and returns hours from that. here i am getting both the total hours but i need to get individual month hours from that.

Regards,
kumar

Answer (score 4):

Use *datediff*

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Duration
(
    startDate datetime2
    ,endDate datetime2
)
INSERT INTO dbo.Duration(startDate,endDate)
    VALUES('2007-05-06 12:10:09','2007-05-07 12:10:09')
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,startDate,endDate) AS 'Duration'
FROM dbo.Duration;
-- Returns: 24
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sqlserver datediff function.